# I am not able to write the xpath for dynamic element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am facing a problem in the following scenario. Please help me guys.
Scenario-

1. open URL- https://member.bseindia.com/
2. Click on `<MF>` folder.
3. Click on `<COMMON>`.
4. Click on `<DEC-2017>` folder.
5. Click on `<Current date>` folder

`<Current date>` folder is generating dynamically everyday.

I have written the code but not able to write the xpath for dynamic folder. ex-11-12-2017

```
public class bseIndia
{
    String driverPath = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Public Desktop";
    public WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\Abhishek\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }
    @Test
    public void nav() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\Abhishek\\Document\\geckodriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath+"chromedriver.exe");
        driver.navigate().to("https://member.bseindia.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='FileGridVB1_gvFiles_ctl06_lbFolderItem']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='FileGridVB1_gvFiles_ctl02_lbFolderItem']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='FileGridVB1_gvFiles_ctl02_lbFolderItem']")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='FileGridVB1_gvFiles_ctl06_lbFolderItem']")).click();
        Date date=new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sm = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
        driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@id='FileGridVB1_gvFiles_ctl02_lbFolderItem']"));
        boolean b= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@id='FileGridVB1_gvFiles_ctl02_lbFolderItem']")).contains(sm.format(date));
        if(b==true)
        {
        here I have write the xpath for dynamic folder. 
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't get your problem, what exactly are you trying to do? you already found the folder `if(b==true)`, then you have your folder.

Comment: @Edwin That code assigning `b` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would do things a bit differently. I generally try to look at things like this where I'm repeating actions and try to come up with a general function that will take care of it. In this case, you are clicking a folder given a particular expected name. I would then write a function `clickOnFolder(String folderName)` so that I can handle that case. Then you would just call that function each time you needed to click a folder. The code is below

```
public static void clickOnFolder(String folderName)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(., '" + folderName + "')]")).click();
}
```

Using XPath, we are finding an `A` tag that contains the text of the folder name whether it be "MF" or "COMMON" or today's date. This general function can be used to click any folder.

In your question, one of your issues is that you need to find the folder by today's date. You've asked for the final folder name that contains the day/month/year but you really need it for the containing folder also to do it properly (DEC-2017).

To handle these dates, you just need to get today's date in the desired format and find the `A` tag that represents the folder using XPath. The code to get today's date into the proper format is below.

I've tested the code below and it works.

```
String url = "https://member.bseindia.com/";
driver.navigate().to(url);

// get date formats for folder names
LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
String todaysDate = currentTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
String monthYear = currentTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM-yyyy")).toUpperCase();

clickOnFolder("MF");
clickOnFolder("COMMON");
clickOnFolder(monthYear);
clickOnFolder(todaysDate);
```

---

Your code line that starts with `boolean b` will not work for several reasons.

1. You are using `.findElements()` (plural) which returns a collection so you would need to look at an individual element, e.g. `.get(0)`, to do a comparison.
2. You are comparing a `String` to a `WebElement` which will always fail. What you want is something like `driver.findElement(locator).getText().contains("some string");`.
3. Your date format is using `mm` which in datetime formats means minutes, not months. You want `MM`.